# How do I initialize a generic variable with its min/max possible value (numeric limits)?

Tags: nim-lang

How can I initialize a variable in a generic function with the min/max possible value of underlying generic type? I'm looking for Nim's equivalent of C++'s `std::numeric_limits`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nim does not require a special module for that. The general pattern is to use `low(T)` or `high(T)` to get the min/max possible value of type `T`. The functions are overloaded for all integer types by default. It can be extended easily to float types or any other type by implementing `low` and `high` for them. For instance the following code would work for any standard number type:

```nim
import typetraits # only required for priting the type name

proc high(T: typedesc[SomeReal]): T = Inf
proc low(T: typedesc[SomeReal]): T = NegInf

proc requiresNumericLimits[T]() =
  let minPossible = low(T)
  let maxPossible = high(T)
  echo "Min of type ", name(T), ": ", minPossible
  echo "Max of type ", name(T), ": ", maxPossible

requiresNumericLimits[int]()
requiresNumericLimits[int16]()
requiresNumericLimits[uint16]()
requiresNumericLimits[float32]()
requiresNumericLimits[float64]()
```

Output:

```
Min of type int: -9223372036854775808
Max of type int: 9223372036854775807
Min of type int16: -32768
Max of type int16: 32767
Min of type uint16: 0
Max of type uint16: 65535
Min of type float32: -inf
Max of type float32: inf
Min of type float64: -inf
Max of type float64: inf
```